# What are the generators of polynomials symmetric under a subgroup of the permutation group

Tags: polynomials, symmetry, symmetric-polynomials, fixed-points

I have been studying iterated polynomials, specifically let $P(x)=x^2+c$ and consider the equation $P(P(P(x)))=x$.  After dividing out the solutions of $P(x)=x$, we have six solutions, which obey the following equations:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_{2a}=P(x_{1a})\\
x_{3a}=P(x_{2a})\\
x_{1a}=P(x_{3a})\\
x_{2b}=P(x_{1b})\\
x_{3b}=P(x_{2b})\\
x_{1b}=P(x_{3b})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
These equations are symmetric under $G_0$,  a subgroup of the permutation group.  The generators of $G_0$ are two rotations:
\begin{equation}
x_{1a}\mapsto x_{2a}  \mapsto x_{3a} \mapsto x_{1a} \\
x_{1b}\mapsto x_{2b}  \mapsto x_{3b} \mapsto x_{1b}
\end{equation}
and the interchange
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_{1a} \mapsto x_{1b} \mapsto x_{1a}\\
x_{2a} \mapsto x_{2b} \mapsto x_{2a}\\
x_{3a} \mapsto x_{3b} \mapsto x_{3a}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

My question is what are the generators of polynomials invariant under $G_0$.
There are many polynomials invariant under $G_0$ but not the permutation group $P_6$.
These include
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
s1=(x_{1a}+x_{2a}+x_{3a})(x_{1b}+x_{2b}+x_{3b})\\
s2=x_{1a} x_{2a}+x_{2a} x_{3a}+x_{3a}x_{1a}+x_{1b} x_{2b}+x_{2b} x_{3b}+x_{3b}x_{1b}\\
s3=x_{1a} x_{2a}^2+x_{2a} x_{3a}^2+x_{3a}x_{1a}^2+x_{1b} x_{2b}^2+x_{2b} x_{3b}^2+x_{3b}x_{1b}^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Note that $s1$ and $s2$ are invariant under single interchanges such as $x_{1a} \mapsto x_{2a} \mapsto x{1a}$, which is not in $G_0$.  $s3$ is only invariant under $G_0$.

Again, to be clear, what is a set of polynomials (which will likely include $s1, s2$, and $s3$)such that any polynomial invariant under $G_0$ can be expressed algebraically as an expression in $s1, s2, s3, ...$?  Is this set finite?
Related question; can $s1, s2, s3, etc.$ be expressed as rational functions of c?  Remember c?  $P(x)= x^2+c$.